# Why can't I enter decimals in QGIS r.water.outlet?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I am using the latest version of QGIS 2.14.  I have a raster DEM file. I ran the `r.watershed` and it created all the raster layers for flow direction, stream, etc.

My next step is to run r.water.outlet to subdivide a basin.  In the `r.water.outlet` input window, more specifically the northing and easting input text box, the built in filter does not allow me to enter numbers past the decimal point.

Example: for a point at -73 35 45.5 E when I tried to enter -73.35455 the most that I can enter is -73. and no numbers past the decimal point.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you using r.water.outlet from the Processing toolbox? I cannot reproduce the issue so far.

Comment: Not from the processing toolbox, from the dialog box that pop up once you click on the grass list of command.

Comment: Yes it is from the Processing toolbox. Sorry for the wrong statement earlier posted.

Comment: I was able to load the needed rasters to create a mapset in the grass plugin, and run r.watershe, and r.water.outlet.  In r.water.outlet through the grass plugin I was able to enter the coordinates with decimals.  The program run, although the results is not the best.  The issue is running r.water.outlet through the processing toolbox.  Thanks for showing me the other option of grass plugin.  I will use it more often.

Comment: A side note:  -73 35 45.5 !=  -73.35455. You have to convert DD MM SS to decimal degrees.

Answer (score 2):

Looks fine here in the Processing toolbox

[image]

as well as with the GRASS plugin 2.0 in QGIS 2.14 on Win8

[image]

Comment: I have to learn to create the mapset.  I got this far to the screen that you show, and was able to enter the coordinate with decimals.  However I got some error messages which is basically from my lack of knowledge in using mapset.  I was running r.water.outlet not thru the grass plugin but through the processing toolbox.  I advise you wrong earlier.  It is through the processing tool box dialog box. Sorru for the confusion.

Comment: R.water.oulet loaded from the processing tool box does not allow numbers past the decimal point in the coordinate input text field. Is this a bug?

Comment: The r.water.outlet dialog window from the processing tool box that comes up on my screen is different than the one you showed.  The dialog window has two texts entries, one named easting coordinate of outlet point, and one named northing coordinate of outlet point. The one you showed combined the northing and easting.

Comment: Then I suggest that you delete your old processing version

Comment: I reinstalled QGIS, Grass 7, OSGEO4W64, and MSYS64.  In the processing toolbox I reconfigured the different plugin.  When I opened GRASS GIS 7 commands [148 geoalgorithms] and more specifically r.water.oulet, the window that open is different than the one you showed.  My operating system is a Windows 10, and running QGIS on 64 bits. Thanks for your help.  I will run r.water.outlet through Grass 7 plugin like you suggested.

Comment: Delete the Processing folder from your user directory. There is a new version of Processing in the OSGeo4W directory which is hidden by the version in your user directory.

Comment: I got it.  Like you said I had to go in my window user account and delete the .gis and .gis2 directory where the processing subdirectory resides.  I reinstalled qgis, and now I have the new updated window for r.water.oulet. Thank you for your patience.  I would have never thought that I was running a ghost copy of grass plugin.